# How can I code the result of this api request in visual studio

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio, postman

I am working on a Covid-19 Tracker Project which requires me to get and use api data through the URL https://thevirustracker.com/free-api?global=stats recommended on the website https://thevirustracker.com/api but for some reason I can neither access the suggested website nor can I get the required data through the suggested URL.

Instead I'm trying to do it through https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/all?yesterday but the result has a slightly different structure and therefore I'm finding it hard to code in line 48 of my GlobalData.js file on Visual Studio in order to display the *"cases"* figure of the result of the api GET request under the *"Global Data as of Today"* in the first Paper section of the app.
Can someone please help me out?

[Pic Result of api GET request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G24fk.jpg)

[Pic GlobalData.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAefs.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Fetch api sends always you a promise so in console you can see that is a promise.

**try this you will get your actual data in console.**

```js
fetch('https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/all?yesterday')
   .then((res)=>res.json())
   .then((data)=>console.log(data))
   .catch((err)=>console.log(err))
```